# IOS - Keyboard disappear from screen when multitasking is enabled

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, multitasking

and thank you in advance.
I’m currently developing an app for iOS in swift, and I have a screen where the user can insert some text.
It works great but i noticed a strange thing.
If the app is on screen and if the user enable the “multitasking”, the keyboard disappears from the screen.
The app doesn’t freeze. 
Is there a way to fix this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Listen `UIApplicationWillResignActive` event through `NSNotificationCenter` and remember your currently active `UITextView` or `UITextField`. And then listen `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` event through `NSNotificationCenter` and call `becomeFirstResponder()` method on your previously active `UITextView` or `UITextField`.

Comment: @CosmosMan thank you! That helped!